# How to configure Dual Code Boot Mode in CubeMX

Tags: c, arm, stm32

In CubeMX my project has the option "Dual Core Boot Mode" = ​"Both CPUs booting at once". After generating code, I compile it in Keil. Linker complains:

"

Build target 'new from scratch Eval_CM7'

linking...

new from scratch Eval_CM7\new from scratch Eval_CM7.sct(7): error: L6235E: More than one section matches selector - cannot all be FIRST/LAST.

Not enough information to list image symbols.

Not enough information to list load addresses in the image map.

Finished: 2 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.

"new from scratch Eval_CM7\new from scratch Eval_CM7.axf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).

"

Should I fix something in CubeMX or in Keil options?

Comment: what stm are you using? How does it works when not doing this?

Comment: I tried DualCore STM32H747XI. Before I used successfully SingleCore STM32F745VI, worked great with CubeMX+Keil, having single .sct file. Now with DualCores I have two .sct files, almost identical, memory addresses are different. Linker is confused.
Apparently I compiled in Keil and run two DualCore examples available: DualCoreBlinky and FPU-Fractal. They work, but they are non-CubeMX. They have similar .sct files, with different memory addresses. Linker is Ok with them.

Comment: it's all here: 
https://developer.arm.com/docs/100070/0612/scatter-loading-features​​
a lot of reading, and no any simple working example for the DualCore MCU...


Error L6235E: More than one section matches selector - cannot all be FIRST/LAST.

See the following in the armlink User Guide:

Section placement with the FIRST and LAST attributes.
Syntax of an input section description.

Comment: Does the working project use both cpu's? And does it compile in one project? You could look at the memory allignment in the 'options for target' menu. Also are the .s files identical? (between example and cube)

Answer (score 0):

and the solution for Linker cryptic error is: in Keil Application/MDK-ARM folder (which had two files), delete this M4 file

startup_stm32h747xx_CM4.s​

and keep this M7 file

startup_stm32h747xx_CM7.s​

They are exactly the same. Who put two of them, not sure, maybe CubeMX? All other non-CubeMX examples have only single file

startup_stm32h747xx.s​